# Inverse of a matrix using numpy does not give expected results

Tags: python, numpy, encryption, multidimensional-array, cryptography

I am trying to write a code to de-crypt Hill Cipher text. We were taught how to do this manually where we use linear algebra. My code needs me to find the inverse of a square matrix.

Let's say I am doing this manually for a 2x2 matrix. If my matrix is:

```
|1  4 |
|11 11|
```

If I find the determinant(mod 26 because it is after all for the cipher) and the adjoint of the matrix, I'll end up with:

```
|121  44|
|-121 11|
```

I can find the elements mod 26 later, but what i am trying to say is I am going to get whole numbers.

Now to code this, I had a time crunch so I thought I'd use numpy to find the inverse of this matrix instead of writing seperate codes to find inverse and adjoint. This is what I've done:

```
a=[[1,11],[4,11]]
print(linalg.inv(a))
```

When I do it manually,
I get 19 as the determinant

```
Inverse=     1 |11  -4| = 11|11  -4| = |121  -44|
             19|-11  1|     |-11  1|   |-121  11|
```

(I multiplied by 11 because the modular inverse of 19 is 11)
Ok so this was what we were taught. But when I use the above mentioned numpy function: I get:

```
[-0.33333333  0.12121212]
 [ 0.33333333 -0.03030303]]
```

while I was expecting a `[[121 -44],[-121,11]]`.

I don't think I have understood how the numpy function works, which is giving me a wrong result. Please help me try to understand what I can do to obtain my expected results

Comment: Not familiar with your goal, but if you multiply the `numpy` inverse (which is of course correct) by -363 you get your expected result. Just adding that the matrix B is inverse of A if `AB = I` (`I` being the identity matrix) and that's what you get: `np.matmul(a,linalg.inv(a))`.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe your maths is incorrect?

I've obtained the matrix inversion of `{(1,11),(4,11)}` to be `{(-1/3,1/3),(4/33,-1/33)}`.
(You can try it from a online calculator, I used wolframalpha.)

This gives the same output I obtained (as yours):

```
runfile('C:/Users/HP/.spyder-py3/numpyinvtest_for_stackoverflow.py', wdir='C:/Users/HP/.spyder-py3')
[[-0.33333333  0.33333333]
 [ 0.12121212 -0.03030303]]
```

My code:

```
import numpy as np

b = np.array([[1,11],[4,11]])
c = np.linalg.inv(b)

print (c)
```

NumPy is working fine and its functionality here is to inverse the matrix, which is done correctly. I presume you made some errors in the pen-and-paper maths.